# How to convert depth to color in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

Is it possible to convert depth (measured z-distance in BYTE) to color (8 bit Grayscale) in Qt? My input is only a BYTE. I need to convert it to color. Please help

Comment: are you have 256-color palette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `BYTE` is a typedef as follows :

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

As a `BYTE` can represent values from 0 to 255, you can use it directly to create a `QColor object, using the value stored in the byte as the intensity for the red, green and blue values :

```
BYTE depth = 128;

QColor color(depth, depth, depth); // greyscaled color
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `QVariant` class you can convert a byte to a string.
So first convert it to a string then again using `QVariant` class you can convert string to `QColor`.

check this
http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#canConvert

Comment: There is no need to convert through using a string !